# What is the distinction between "graduate school" and "professional school"?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, career-path

I have previously been involved with mentoring high school students as well as undergraduates, who typically don't have a clear understanding of all of the career possibilities available to them and how they might pursue them.

One of the distinctions I typically make is that **"Professional School"** (*e.g. medical, law, physicians assistant, nurse practitioner, dental*) is further training past undergraduate studies that prepares you for entry into a very specific profession/job with a terminal degree. **"Graduate School"** is additional training that prepares you to be an expert in a particular field, but the job opportunities are much more diverse and you may or may not be working toward a terminal degree. One of my college advisors made this distinction to me, and I have carried it forward.

**Is making this distinction between graduate and professional school correct?** 
**Is there another more specific or subtle difference that I am missing?**

What is the true *distinction* between graduate and professional school? - *Or is there not one?*

Comment: Given the professions you listed for "professional school", a very cynical part of me wants to say "salary prospects" ;-)

Comment: nice comment @tonysdg... I wonder where individuals would place MBA programs or other specialized masters programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in my geographic region (Texas, or the US southern states), a professional school implies a curriculum that targets specific skills for a particular vocation. In effect, this is akin to my awkward bastardization of several concepts:

> "Teach a man to fish and he can become a fisherman ... help him learn
>   how to think and he can pursue a career in whatever he wants."

The former refers to a professional/vocational school.  The latter refers to accredited universities with broader range of curriculum missions.  Granted, this reflects my biased perspective: admittedly, vocational schools have a (usually) noble and useful purpose, but proper universities can offer so much more to enrich the whole student, and potentially brighten the intellectual and career outlook for years to come.